# Xamarin Forms 3.6 App Crashing on resume on iOS devices

Tags: c#, ios, google-maps, xamarin.forms, crash

After updating to latest Xamarin Forms nuget v3.6, my app is facing crash issues on Resume and navigating away from screen which contains google maps view

Versions:
Xamarin.Forms v3.6.0.220655,Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps v3.2.0,Xamarin.Google.iOS.Maps v3.0.3

I have tried updating the google maps nuget packages in both portable/ios project to latest stable releases

Need help.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a try catch block inside the OnResume method? It could be a bug as well which is worth reporting on the GitHub repo if it only occurs in this version.

Comment: Any code or exception message/stacktrace? Withou any further information, it'll be hard to give a profound answer.